# Find duplicate values in array with drools

Tags: arrays, drools, jbpm

I have some rules made with Drools. Each one add values to one array.
The problem I have is that I need to check this conditions:

- Check if determinate value is in the array. If true, a new value is added after or before that.
- The final step is check the array. If it has repeat values, the rule will delete them.

This is the structure of my initial rules:

```
rule "add value"
salience 500

      when
                products: Products($items : items)
                item : EprItem() from $items
                products: Products( totalAmount > 0 && < 999999999 )
      then
                Approver approver = new Approver();
                approver.setEmployeeNumber("11111");
                products.getApprovalPath().add(approver);
end
```

Is there a way to know if a value is duplicated in the array? And how can I know what is the index of the element I get in the variable items, to add the value after or before?

Comment: And what was the question?

Comment: sorry, I put it in the title. Now is in the question :)

Comment: An array is not a good data structure to begin with - that's why java.util contains a number of Collections better suited to processing. In order to detect a duplicate in an array, you should write a DRL function and call that.

Comment: Do you mean $items? This refers to Products.items - is this an array? If so, $items refers to the entire array and so it is not associated with an index.

Comment: but In drools, how can I do  that? I have problems writing the condition to say "if the list has duplicates, then do this"

Comment: ah, let me edit the code to add the way I get an element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, the way this rule is written is rather circuitous.

```
when
products: Products( totalAmount > 0 && < 999999999 )
then
```

is sufficient.

The CE `item : EprItem() from $items` will cause to fire the rule once for each element in $items - which is not what you want.

To see whether there are any duplicates, write a DRL function (or a static Java method) `hasDuplicates` that has one parameter of the type of Product.items and returns true if there are duplicates and call it like this:

```
when
products: Products( hasDuplicates(products.getItems()) )
```